# ajax form : success doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I am trying to use ajaxForm(options) to execute some methods before submitting the form.

Below are the options that I have set:

```
var options = {
                target : '#output1',
                success : showJsonResponse,
                beforeSubmit : validateFieldNotEmptyCallLoc,
                dataType : 'json'
            };

$('#formId').ajaxForm(options);
```

Regardless of what beforeSubmit returns ; true or false, success method -> showJsonResponse is called.
Some article said "success " is replaced by "done" since jquery 1.8. Tried that 
doesn't like that "done" thing either

**Edit 1**

```
<input id="btn-font" type="submit" onclick="return callAjaxSubmitFunction();">
```

onclick function makes the `$("#formId").submit();`

Comment: and the url? where you place it?

Comment: what does "done" have to do with the plugin you are using? "ajax" and "ajaxForm" are two completely different things.

Comment: @Leandro it's on the form, theoretically

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#validation i can't recreate your problem.

Comment: Most likely your validate callback is wrong.

Comment: @kevin the validate callback returns true or false

Comment: @JavaQuest prove it. My expectation is that this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @KevinB you were absolutely correct. I messed up the validate callback function, it wasn't returning false; so never stopped the form from being submitted.
Relatively new to javascript, used to java which gives compilation error right away if I miss return in non-void function

Answer (score 1):

Made a stupid mistake of not returning the false in my beforeSubmit callback function. So it never stopped the form from being submitted.
Thanks to @kevinB !